# How to log user in to multiple drupal sites?

Tags: 7, users

I have multiple drupal sites on the same server (VPS). Thise sites has separated d7 core and db. All sites has own domains: domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com..

When user logs in to one site I need him to log also in to the another site.
This should be done in single sign on so user does not have to log first to one site and then to another.

How to automatically log user in to the both/multiple sites?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Multisite Login](https://drupal.org/project/multisite_login) module

> Multisite Login allows a user to login to all sites in a multisite
> configuration, even though the multisites do not share domain names.
>
> NOTE: if you are using several sites on the same domain (ex.
> politicker.com, nj.politicker.com, ny.politicker.com, etc.), then you
> do not need this module. The multisite functionality in Drupal core
> has the ability to share logins for sites like these without
> additional modules.

also take a look at [CAS](https://drupal.org/project/cas) module.

Comment: Multisite-module readme.txt says: ** REQUIREMENTS **

"You must be:
  - using a multisite installation
  - using a separate database for each site (no table prefixing, though the code could be 
    modified to allow for this, patches welcome). 
  - sharing the users table across all sites (If this is not you, what are you hoping that this module
    will do for you?)." I am NOT using multisite installation.